# Display all website products

Tags: magento-1.9, products, websites

I have 1 magento instance with 2 websites set up inside it. 
example.com/website1
example.com/website2

Products are either assigned to website 1 or website 2. However on the frontend I want customers to be able to view products from website 1 & 2 without changing websites.

Is this possible?

Comment: It is not possible.

Comment: I am presuming that it is possible to the override the core of magento so that it doesn't look at the scope of the product on the frontend??

Comment: ok, if you want to customers to be able to view all products in a both store, without changing the website, why are you have 2 website? please tell more in your question.

Comment: Because in the backend for admins I want to limit the scope. So website 1 admins can only view website 1 products.